# Can We change phrasal verbs into all other tenses?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I use other verb forms of any phrasal verbs?

For an instance, Can the phrasal verb `give in` be use used as `gave in`, `giving in`, `will give in` and so?

Comment: Yes, because "give" + "in" do not form a verb. It is only the lexeme "give" that is a verb. "In" is a preposition, a separate constituent at word level. In fact, the term 'phrasal verb' is a misnomer and best replaced with the term "verbal idiom".

Comment: It would be better to include a couple of examples using *give in* as a phrasal verb. Then it should be possible to see if the substitutions carry the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They can. Why would you think that they cannot be inflected? Given the importance of verb inflections to convey differences in meaning in English, a verb that cannot be inflected would be of very limited use.

Comment: I am a learner, I haven't been seeing phrasal verb in any other forms in any of the movies or serials till now. That is why I am confused.

Comment: It is very easy to google "gave up" or "giving up" and find lots of examples.